# Batch call another batch and use output as variable

Tags: string, variables, batch-file

I'm trying to compare a bunch of files with names like

> "BD12-CD9.txt"

to folders named

> "BD12-CD9 - somefoldername"

I'm removing the .txt extension to get the ID code "BD12-CD9" and want to check if the folder name contains the code.

I can't figure out how to do this without an if statement that compares strings exactly. (might be an easy solution here like jQuery's indexOf())

So I need to strip the ID code from the file name and do a direct comparison.

The problem is the ids and names are not always exactly the same length e.g. "BD12-CD10.txt" so I can't just do "set folderName2=!folderName:~0,8!"

I found a strlength function and put it in another batch file called strlen.bat and it works great, echoing the length of my stripped ID codes. How do I use the echoed value though?

move.bat

```
@echo off
@setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "errfolderpath=C:\Testing\Moving txt files automatically\"
echo.
for %%x in (*.*) do (
    set fileName=%%x
    set fileName2=!fileName!
    set fileName2=!fileName2:~0,-4!
    call strlen !fileName2! 
    FOR /D %%K in ("%errfolderpath%*") DO (
        SET folderName=%%~nK
        set folderName2=!folderName!
        set folderName2=!folderName:~0,11!
        echo folder: !folderName2!, file: !fileName2!
        if !folderName2! == !fileName2! echo MOVE '!fileName!' to '!folderName!'
    )
    echo %_len%      
    echo.   
)
PAUSE
```

strlen.bat

```
@echo off
:: strlen.bat
:: http://acm.zhihua-lai.com
if [%1] EQU [] goto end
 :loop
    if [%1] EQU [] goto end
    set _len=0
    set _str=%1
    set _subs=%_str%
    :getlen     
        if not defined _subs goto result
        :: remove first letter until empty
        set _subs=%_subs:~1%
        set /a _len+=1
        goto getlen
    :result
        echo %_len%        
        shift
        goto loop
:end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the batch file variable usage, if you look to the code, a variable called `_len` is defined. This variable is then echoed to console, but is not removed (no reasignation, no endlocal, ...) , so just use it.

Anyway, it is easier than it seems.

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
    set "errfolderpath=C:\Testing\Moving txt files automatically"
    for %%a in (*.txt) do (
        set "notMoved=1"
        for %%b in ("%errorfolderpath%\%%~na*") do if defined notMoved (
            set "notMoved="
            move "%%~fa" "%%~fb"
        )
    )
```

For each file, search a folder with the same prefix (the name of the file referenced in `%%a`, without extension, is `%%~na`). If found, move the file (the full path to the file is `%%~fa`) to the target folder and use a switch variable to "mark" the file as moved to avoid problems in the case of two folders with the same prefix (that will be retrieved in the inner `for %%b`) .

Comment: Thanks MC ND, I'm almost there. Do you know how I would change this:
`set folderName2=!folderName:~0,11!`
to use !_len! instead of 11?

Comment: @user1425011 `for %%z in (!_len!) do set folderName2=!folderName:~0,%%z!`